# Modificadores root e active em java

Tags: java

Meu professor passou uns slides e ele citou dois modificadores o `root` e o `Active` porem nunca ouvi falar deles e pelo que pesquisei eles não existem em java, alguém pode dar uma explicada melhor? Existe algo parecido em java que faça isso?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Os modificadores ROOT e ACTIVE provavelmente foram ensinados em Programação Orientada a Objetos, onde seu professor pode estar utilizando Java como linguagem de exemplo. Apesar de não serem atributos de classe da linguagem Java, o aprendizado de seus conceitos são essenciais para compreensão da POO como um todo.

Comment: Você poderia me citar um exemplo de linguagem de programação que utiliza estes modificadores? Ou eles são apenas conceitos mesmo?